# Jdbc​Sink​Connector to ClickHouse

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, clickhouse

Is it possible to transfer data from Kafka topic into Clickhouse table via Jdbc​Sink​Connector?
Everything works good with Postgres. But when trying to use Clickhouse (settings are identical) I get error:

> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: null (FLOAT32) type
>   doesn't have a mapping to the SQL database column type    at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.getSqlType(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:1727)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.writeColumnSpec(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:1643)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.lambda$writeColumnsSpec$33(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:1632)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.ExpressionBuilder.append(ExpressionBuilder.java:558)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.ExpressionBuilder$BasicListBuilder.of(ExpressionBuilder.java:597)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.writeColumnsSpec(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:1634)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.buildCreateTableStatement(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:1557)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure.create(DbStructure.java:91)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure.createOrAmendIfNecessary(DbStructure.java:61)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.add(BufferedRecords.java:121)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:66)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:538)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Topic schema:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "name",
  "namespace": "name.space",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "brakeLinePressure",
      "type": "float"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What jbdc driver are you using?

Comment: This https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc. clickhouse-jdbc-0.2.4.jar and clickhouse-jdbc-0.2.4-shaded.jar versions.

Comment: Are you able to use JdbcSinkConnector for clickhouse. I am facing similar issue.